# How to display a column in random order AND skip empty cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list in column A that I'd like to put in random order in column B. However, column A will constantly be added to, so it's not a finite number of cells. I would like a formula that will automatically expand to include new data, but I haven't been able to do so without also including the blank cells in the rest of the column.

I've tried QUERY, SORT and FILTER but can't seem to get it right. 
Here's what I have currently:

```
=sort(A:A,arrayFormula(randbetween(sign(row(A:A)),1000000)),true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's been a month and OP seems not interested so I have removed the Excel tag and suggest:

```
=ArrayFormula(SORT(filter(A:A,A:A<>""),RANDBETWEEN(0+0*SIGN(ROW(indirect("A1"&":A"&count(A:A)))),1E+100),RANDBETWEEN(0,1)))
```